# \psdiabox is too big

Tags: pstricks, boxes

How can I reduce the size of a `\psdiabox`, for instance:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.35}
\begin{pspicture}(9.261250,-52.662503)(52.977702,-0.950000)
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1cm,colsep=.5cm]
        & \rput[tc](30.5,-19.5){\psdiabox
            { \begin{tabular}{c}
                ?`$Pueden \, estar \, repetidos$ \\
                $los \, p \, que \, vaya \, a \, tomar?$ \\
                \end{tabular} }}
        \end{psmatrix}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1792344 I've reduced the code to a MWE; the original one is still available in the revision history. May I ask why are you using math mode in the tabular? It's also not very clear what you mean by "too big".

Comment: Without math code the diamond is too big.

Comment: This feature is a problem to design flowcharts!!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can reduce `framesep=0pt`, and you can reduce the spaces left and right of the `tabular` using `@{}c@{}` instead of `c`.

But the main point is, that the width of `\psdiabox` is twice its height. To change that, you can redefine the internal command `\tx@Diamond` in order to change the aspect ratio:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\pst@def{Diamond}<%
  /mtrx CM def 
  T rotate 
  1.2 mul /h ED % added the 1.2 mul
  0.8 mul /w ED % added the 0.8 mul
  dup 0 eq { pop } { CLW mul neg 
    /d ED 
    /a w h Atan def 
    /h d a sin Div h add def 
    /w d a cos Div w add def } ifelse 
  mark w 2 div h 2 div w 0 0 h neg w neg 0 0 h w 2 div h 2 div 
  /ArrowA { moveto } def 
  /ArrowB { } def 
  false Line 
  closepath mtrx setmatrix
>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,2)
  \rput(3,1){%
    \psdiabox[framesep=0pt]
      { \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}c@{}}
        ?`Pueden estar repetidos\\
        los p que vaya a tomar? \\
      \end{tabular}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Here, I changed the height by a factor of `1.2`, and the width by `0.8`. You can change it as you like.

If you have other diamonds, which shouldn't be changed, then you must make this change locally.

I strongly recommend you to have a look at `pst-tree`, see `texdoc pst-tree` and browse through the documentation! For automatic node alignment and node connections.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\psdiabox{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    ?`$Pueden \, estar \, repetidos$ \\
    $los \, p \, que \, vaya \, a \, tomar?$ \\
\end{tabular}}
%
\psdiabox{%
\makebox[0.7\width]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    ?`$Pueden \, estar \, repetidos$ \\
    $los \, p \, que \, vaya \, a \, tomar?$ \\
\end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there was an easier solution `:)`.

Comment: Jjejeje thanks for your help too. And sorry for my own answer. Sometimes is very confused to me the english language